# Trying to understand Node callback syntax

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am reverse engineering one of the open source [implementations](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-saml2) of SAML based Single Sign on (SSO)

When the SSO is successful I get a POST from my idp(identity provider) and following function is called:

```
router.post('/acs/:idp?', function (req, res, next) {
  console.log('got a post from idp');
    var _idp, _sp;
    if (req.params.idp === 'onelogin') {
      console.log('the idp is onelogin or vidm in this case');
        _idp = oneLoginIdP;
        _sp = olsp;
    } else {
        _idp = idp;
        _sp = sp;
    }
    _sp.parseLoginResponse(_idp, 'post', req, function (parseResult) {
      console.log('trying to parse assertion to see if it is valid');
      console.log('name id'+parseResult.extract.nameid);

        if (parseResult.extract.nameid) {
            res.render('login', {
                title: 'Processing',
                isSSOLogin: true,
                email: parseResult.extract.nameid
            });
        } else {
            req.flash('info', 'Unexpected error');
            res.redirect('/login');
        }
    });
});
```

Now, as we can see this function calls a function called parseLoginResponse on the serverivceprovider object (_sp). parseLoginResponse looks like following:

```
ServiceProvider.prototype.parseLoginResponse = function parseLoginResponse(idp, binding, req, parseCallback) {
        return this.abstractBindingParser({
            parserFormat:
            [
            {
                localName: 'StatusCode',
                attributes: ['Value']
            },
            {
                localName: 'Conditions',
                attributes: ['NotBefore', 'NotOnOrAfter']
            },
            'Audience',
            'Issuer',
            'NameID',
            {
                localName: 'Signature',
                extractEntireBody: true
            },
            {
                localName: {
                    tag: 'Attribute',
                    key: 'Name'
                },
                valueTag: 'AttributeValue'
            }
          ],
            checkSignature: this.entityMeta.isWantAssertionsSigned(),
            from: idp,
            supportBindings: ['post'],
            parserType: 'SAMLResponse',
            actionType: 'login'
        }, binding, req, idp.entityMeta, parseCallback);
    };
```

My three specific Questions:

1. `How is the callback working for parseCallback method.`
2. `I am new to javascript so I don't get at which exact line parseCallback is receiving it's argument i.e parseResult?`
3. I can print following line succefully in my parseCallback:

   ```
   console.log('name id'+parseResult.extract.nameid);
   ```

BUT I can't find a way to print attributes that contain notbefore and notonorafter time. `How can I print attributes section of parseResult or the commplete parseResult argument?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Method `this.abstractBindingParser();` Takes 5 arguments. Last of them - `parseCallback` function. So you passing this function inside `this.abstractBindingParser()`. It will be called internally inside `this.abstractBindingParser()`;

You don't know how exactly it is called internally, which params are passed to `parseCallback`. You can refer to documentation for system that you use, or you can use magic variable `arguments`. Place `console.log(arguments);` after `console.log('name id' + parseResult.extract.nameid);`

Comment: Thanks!  console.log(arguments); was all I needed.